# Documentation Creation in Mathematica 12.1

Tags: version-12

Last year, there was a [LiveCEO discussion](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cPOuE7JQv_4) of refreshing the user-facing documentation creation modules for the next version of Mathematica.  Has that made it into the recently released Mathematica 12.1?  If so, how does one access these tools in Mathematica 12.1?

Comment: I do not know the answer, so I will not post a self-answer.

Comment: No, it did not.

Comment: Thanks, can you post it as an answer?

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have been more accurate and say that I did not see it included, but I've found things in the "what's new" section that I have somehow missed throughout the beta testing period.